# How to dynamically select names on Tableau and go to required Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I am new to Tableau and I am trying to workout how I can link dashboards based on a selection by a user.

I am currently trying to workout how i can dynamically select a user from a list and then this will take me to another dashboard and display stats etc for that user. I am not sure if its possible in Tableau but what I would like to do is build templates for each level of user in order for the right data to be display.

For example:

Senior Manager Dashboard
will list Junior Managers stats

If i select Manager Humpty

this will then take me to all of Humptys stats broken down by his agents etc.

Is this something that I can do in Tableau?

Apologies for the vague but not come across anything on Google or YouTube..

Answer (score 1):

If its just a static list of users with dashboards for each you could create a table of contents dashboard for them with actions against them like in the below example.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-table-contents-navigate-other-dashboards

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL filtering capabilities. You create a template detail worksheet and pass in the manager information on the URL to dynamically filter the detail worksheet based on who you select on the first sheet with the list of managers.

1. Build a worksheet that has the names of all managers.
2. Build a second worksheet that has the details of the managers. It's okay during design to have it show everyone.
3. On the first sheet, set up a URL action filter pointed to the second sheet. In the URL action, pass in a URL parameter for the person's ID or name, depending on how your data is structured.

The basic pattern for URL filter parameters is `http://servername/views/workbook/sheet?Field_Name=Value`. Value is dynamic when you set up the URL action.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow user Filter:

step1:

create a calculated field and name it as User Filter and create same as I have describe in link.[Creation of User Filter calculated field]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpJdB.png

Note: you should have one unique Id as client code and in the link there is no 3 which describe that client code length is 3 so in formula I have written 3 so change according to your unique Id.

Step2

Place this calculated field as User filter in filter section and allow option as true and then select option as "Apply to all worksheet".
Describe in the link as [User Filter]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhIhn.png

Hope this will work